# Getting compile error from React Component useState

Tags: reactjs

[image: This is the error I am getting from my React component]

This is the code of the component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import NavBar from './Navbar'
import axios from 'axios'
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

function mygroups() {
    let profile_id = localStorage.getItem('profile_id')
    const [group, setgroup]=useState([])
    
   useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`/getgroups?profile_id=${profile_id}`)
        .then(res=>setgroup(res.data))
        .then(res=>{
            //localStorage.setItem("screen_name",res.data.screenname)
            //localStorage.setItem("profile_id",res.data._id)
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar /> 
            <h3 className='bg-primary p-2 text-center'>Groups</h3>
            {
                group.map((data,key)=>(
                   <div className='container'>
                        <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                        <span className='badge badge-dart p-2'>{data.name}</span>
                        <h6 className='text-white mt-4'>{data.no_members}</h6>
                        <hr style={{border:'1pz dotted white'}} />
                   </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default mygroups
```

This was based off from another component that works perfectly fine.  I just changed the variable names.  Even when I comment out all of the code and just have the `const [group, setgroup]=useState([])`, I get this compile error right away.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: All react elements names should be capitaliced: `function Mygroups() { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell React that `mygroups` is a *functional component* rather than a regular function, otherwise it won't permit you to use hooks in it. Change

```
function mygroups() {
```

to

```
function Mygroups() {
```

Comment: Thank you from a very noobie React student.